# Embedding images files in sandboxed webpart

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, sharepoint-online

Fairly new to SharePoint development but have been asked to into developing some simple web part features for a solution we're working on.

I need to add some basic image/logo files into the .wsp for use as buttons/links. Being uploaded to SharePoint online they need to be packaged rather than mapped folders. I'm struggling to get the images to package so they will display correctly once deployed or uploaded but they display fine in VS2010.

I'm done a whole bunch of searching and trying the different Build Actions and adding as resources but then was unsure how to reference them in the HTML.

I know this is likely a simple fix but any hints would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy files to SharePoint Online by using modules.

In detail files (such as images, script files or css files) need to be stored in a library in SharePoint Online, it isn't allowed to write directly to the filesystem.

Depending on the given SiteTemplate you can tie to an existing library eg 'Site Assets', if no library is present you've to create a new one as part of your solution.

In addition you've to ensure that every user has access to the library, in order to consume the image.